# Google webmasters API authentication

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

I'm using these scripts: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/download-search-queries-data-using.html
to get search results queries however when I run the script appears:

*line 793, in ProgrammaticLogin
    raise BadAuthentication, 'Incorrect username or password'
gdata.service.BadAuthentication: Incorrect username or password*

My user and password are correct however keep appearing that error. Is this API does not longer work or Do I have to do something else to allow me using the Google webmasters API?

I'd appreciate any help you can provide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you're querying was deprecated a few months ago. You can soon achieve the same thing with the [Google Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/), specifically, the `webmasters.searchanalytics.query` endpoint. See the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/) for more details (search for Webmaster Tools).